# Socket programming and arrays

Tags: arrays, sockets, file-descriptor

Hello i am trying to create 2 programms that communicate throught TCP sockets, on C++. I know how to use write() and read() functions but I encounter a problem when I try to send array from one programm to another.
To be more specific I try to  send an array of chars from the one side and read it to another but it dont works.

The array I try to send is defined this way:

```
char** list=new char[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
char[i]=new char[25]
}

char[0]="Hello";
char[1]="world";
char[2]="this";
char[3]="is";
char[4]="a test";
```

and I write it to the socket this way:

```
 void sendtosocket(.. , char array[]) { 
    int size=5*sizeof(char[25]);
    write(sock, &size, sizeof(int))
        write(sock,&array,size); 
}
```

and from the other side I try to read it this way:

```
void readfromsocket(..){

read(sock, &size, sizeof(int));  
char test[5][25];
cout<<size<<" bytes must be read"<<endl;

 read(newsock,&test,size);              

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 cout<<test[i]<<endl;

}
```

the output I get is

> I must read 125 bytes
>
> Hello
>
> s
>
> test

Can you help me? thanks in advance!
Consider that connections and sockets are working fine!

Comment: For C++, consider using the Boost::asio (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or OnPosix (http://onposix.sourceforge.net) libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many problems here... I'll try to point you some problems, but take in consideration that some of them are about C++ basics.

First of all, in:

```
char** list=new char[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
char[i]=new char[25]
}

char[0]="Hello";
char[1]="world";
char[2]="this";
char[3]="is";
char[4]="a test";
```

You are not filling your array, or at least you are allocating memory for nothing. You are pointing the pointers of your array to the place where the const chars "Hello", "wold" is located and loosing the memory allocated in "char[i]=new char[25]" . Take care with memory operations.

Taking this in consideration, you don't know the content of the values after the "Hello\0", and you are trying to send 125 continuous bytes...

In other order of things, in:

```
 void sendtosocket(.. , char array[]) { 
    int size=5*sizeof(char[25]);
    write(sock, &size, sizeof(int))
        write(sock,&array,size); 
}
```

I assume that you are considering that the array is in continuous memory. Well, this is absolutely wrong. Please check the intialization of your variable, and think about how could it be sent.

Comment: Yes my assumption ,to believe that was in continuous memory was very wrong, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously wrong:

```
char** list=new char[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    char[i]=new char[25]
}

char[0]="Hello";
char[1]="world";
char[2]="this";
char[3]="is";
char[4]="a test";
```

What you probably meant was:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

char* list[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    list[i]=new char[25];
}

std::strcpy(list[0], "Hello");
std::strcpy(list[1], "world");
std::strcpy(list[2], "this");
std::strcpy(list[3], "is");
std::strcpy(list[4], "a test");
```